# Cannot read the property of undefined error in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Here is my simple jade script.

`ul - each user in users 
li #{user.username}` .

I will get cannot read the property username of undefined error.

Comment: Can you show the code also?

Comment: username or the user looks undefined. log them to the console to see which one is problematic.

Comment: I will get the correct key value in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that the formatting is wrong so it won't be interpreting the script correctly, should look more like

```
ul
  each user in users
    li #{user.username}
```